# Vim : Substitute command doesn't replace all matched words

Tags: vim

example following:

```
aa aa aa
bb aa bb aa
cc dd aa bb aa
```

visual selection 3 line above, and command execute with `:'<,'>s/aa/ee/g`

result:

```
ee aa aa
bb ee bb aa
cc dd ee bb aa
```

how to replace all matched words?

Comment: Do you have `'gdefault'` set? Do `:verbose set gdefault?`

Comment: @PeterRincker Search_and_replace in vim wiki show the `g` in command `:'<,'>s/aa/ee/g` means `'gdefault'`

Comment: If you have `set gdefault`, using `/g` in a substitution cancels it and your substitution is only performed on the first match. Hence Peter's (who knows full well how `gdefault` works) question.